# How to pass custom parameter in TChromium

Tags: delphi, tchromium

I'm interested if there's any way possible for a custom parameter to be sent with every request in TCHromium (DCEF3, with Delphi XE3). Like the "Send a ‘Do Not Track’ request with your browsing traffic" option in Google Chrome.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the `OnBeforeBrowse` or `OnBeforeResourceLoad` event, and in it, modify the headers of the `request` parameter.